# How disable handlers of Bootstrap Datepicker which delete value when "delete" key pressed?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

From manual:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keybinds

> 'delete': function () {
>               this.clear();
>           }

I try to disable handler:

```
keyBinds: {'delete': function() {} }
```

But it's don't effect. 
How make when "delete" key pressed, clear only one symbol from cursor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use null value instead of function.
    keyBinds: {
        'delete':null
    }

Comment: I need to "delete" key to del the symbol after cursor

Comment: It gain back standard behavior of "delete" key which is deleting symbol after cursor.

Comment: I know this is an old post but how can I keep all the other default OPTIONS and only remove the delete option? @Vitas